# Has Ukraine implemented section 11 of the Minsk II agreement?

Tags: armed-conflict, ukraine, civil-war, peace-treaty, donbass

The [Minsk II Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minsk_II#Measures) calls for

> (2) Pull-out of all heavy weapons by both sides to equal distance with the aim of creation of a security zone on minimum 50 kilometres (31 mi) apart for artillery of 100mm calibre or more, and a security zone of 70 kilometres (43 mi) for multiple rocket launchers (MRLS) and 140 kilometres (87 mi) for MLRS Tornado-S, Uragan, Smerch, and Tochka U tactical missile systems:
>   for Ukrainian troops, from actual line of contact;
>   for armed formations of particular districts of Donetsk and Luhansk oblasts of Ukraine, from the contact line in accordance with the Minsk Memorandum as of 19 September 2014
>   The pullout of the above-mentioned heavy weapons must start no later than the second day after the start of the ceasefire and finish within 14 days.
>   This process will be assisted by OSCE with the support of the Trilateral Contact Group.

and

> (11) Constitutional reform in Ukraine, with a new constitution to come into effect by the end of 2015, the key element of which is decentralisation (taking into account peculiarities of particular districts of Donetsk and Luhansk oblasts, agreed with representatives of these districts), and also approval of permanent legislation on the special status of particular districts of Donetsk and Luhansk oblasts in accordance with the measures spelt out in the attached footnote,[note 1] by the end of 2015.
>   Notes:
>
> > The following measures are to be included in the Ukrainian law "On temporary Order of Local Self-Governance in Particular Districts of Donetsk and Luhansk Oblasts":
> >     Freedom from punishment, harassment, and discrimination of persons connected with the events that took place in particular districts of Donetsk and Luhansk oblasts
> >     Right of language self-determination
> >     Participation of local self-government in the appointment of the heads of prosecutors' offices and courts in the particular districts of Donetsk and Luhansk oblasts
> >     The possibility for central executive bodies to conclude agreements with relevant local authorities on economic, social, and cultural development of particular districts of Donetsk and Luhansk oblasts
> >     The state will provide support for the socio-economic development of particular districts of Donetsk and Luhansk oblasts
> >     Assistance from central executive bodies for cross-border cooperation by particular districts of Donetsk and Luhansk oblasts with regions of the Russian Federation
> >     The freedom to create people's militia units by decision of local councils to maintain public order in particular districts of Donetsk and Luhansk oblasts
> >     The powers of local council deputies and officials, elected in early elections, appointed by the Verkhovna Rada according to this law, cannot be prematurely terminated.

I see many news reports focusing on the ceasefire aspect, eg. [Almost entire 'grey' zone in Donbas liberated by Ukraine without Minsk deal breach – adviser](https://www.unian.info/war/10391709-almost-entire-grey-zone-in-donbas-liberated-by-ukraine-without-minsk-deal-breach-adviser.html) but I haven't seen any reports on Ukraine's implementation of section 11.

Comment: This is the cornerstone of disagreement between Russia and the West. West interprets Minsk agreements in such order: 1)border control to ukraine 2)constituional reform. Russia and eastern republics interprets in opposite way. And this is really a cornerstone. While this question is not solved, noone would do some steps further.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: no, and why.

Minsk agreements(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minsk_II) are interpreted in a different way by Russia and the West. There are many points, but two are very important:

- control over border with Russia. Now it belongs to new-born people's republics. Russia can support them through border, so it is important. Minsk treaties have point about restoring border control to Ukraine.
- Ukrainian constitutional reform and decentralization.

The key disagreement is in order of executing those two points. If Ukraine gains conrtrol over borders, it can try to strangle republics, like they want (https://www.rt.com/news/ukraine-dnepropetrovsk-crimea-protest-458/), but now cannot. 
Ukraine, from its side, doesn't want to make decentralization.

So, while this disagreement is not resolved, no steps can be done from either side.

About links - you may shout 'wow, RT, how about western media?', but western media tries to ignore the most radical Ukrain politicians. If you somehow want to measure the degreee of Ukraine's radicals, you just may search "nazi torch marches in kiev" on youtube, watch it, then watch german nazi's marches, and then you may try to find out differences.) If you'll find any, really, tell me about it.